# Best practice to parse a JSON object on the client in Java & Android

Tags: java, android, json

In my Android client I want to receive JSON objects from a server. By googling I found a lot of different possibilities how to best parse the InputStream from the Server, but most of them wrote their own parser. Isn't there a library which does this parsing for me? Or how should I best implement it by myself?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is not, as of Java 7, any package ***built into*** the <s>Sun</s> Oracle Java distribution for parsing JSON; for android there is at least `org.json`, though apparently some developers don't like it.

There are, of course, many third-party options.

I have a very lightweight JSON parser which you can use to parse an HTTP content stream.  It's completely free, use at your own risk, etc, etc,.  Details and download on my [website](http://tech.dolhub.com/code/JsonParser).  It should work just fine in the Android VM.

Comment: There are many JSON parsers, both packaged in the Sun Java distribution and/or Android distribution. See @StaxMan answer for examples.

Comment: @Gilbert: I specifically said, "***in*** the Sun Java distribution", not "***for*** the Sun...", meaning in the JVM distributed by Sun, and extended that to Android with sentence structure to indicate that I am less certain about Android.  And there is ***not*** any JSON parsing package in the core JVM.  StaxMan refers to third-party packages (and which are not really lightweight in my opinion).

Comment: As an android developer, I assure you that org.json is available in the JVM distributed with the android platform (although I would not recommend using it).

Comment: @Gilbert: I have amended my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 9):

Are you kidding me? There are more than a dozen JSON parsers on Java platform, and most work fine on Android (see http://json.org/). Two most commonly recommended choices are [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) and [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), and both work nicely to allow you to not only parse and write JSON, but to also bind JSON data directly to and from POJOs.

Comment: As you can see it is almost a year ago that I asked this question. But thanks for the two recommendations.

Comment: Yep, I did notice it... but many times people get to questions via google or Related link. So I figured it's good to sort of complete open ones regardless. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the built in [JSONTokener](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html).  There is an example in that link showing how to use it.

To get response as string:

```
InputStream stream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line + "\n");
}

br.close();
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Yes thanks! That is nice if i already have the string of the json object. but part of my problem is that i don't really know the best way to cast the HttpResponse into a String correctly.

Comment: Ah, yeah, thats can be a pain. See edit.  Basically you get the contents as an inputstream, and then turn that into a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
 private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        try {

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                is.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        return sb.toString();

    }
```

u can parse the input to json by this code... hope this will be useful for you

Comment: Why on earth would you do this when most parsers can just take an InputStream to parse content from?

Answer (score 0):

The Wiktionary example in the SDK gets the contents as an InputStream, turns it into a String, then constructs a new org.json.JSONObject(String) to parse through the result.